# I get this error in my simple SQL statement when trying to retrieve a column from a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2014-localdb

This is my procedure:

```
create proc spasdf
    @sdate int,
    @edate int
as
    DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = @sdate

    WHILE  @LoopCounter <= @edate)
    BEGIN
        SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1

        declare @value varchar(30)

        set @value = '['+@LoopCounter+']'

        select UserID, UserName, @value 
        from vwfinal
END
```

I run it using:

```
spasdf 1,5
```

My expected result is:

```
@value=[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
```

When I passing parameter to my stored procedure it shows this error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spasdf, Line 40
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[' to data type int.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: what is the objective of this query ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the `@LoopCounter` values as a string. Declare the `@value` outside while loop and put the select statement after the while loop.

```
create proc spasdf
@sdate int,
@edate int
as
DECLARE @value varchar(30)=''
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = @sdate
WHILE ( @LoopCounter <= @edate)
BEGIN

    SET 

    @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1
    set @value=@value + ',' + QUOTENAME(@LoopCounter)
END
    set @value=STUFF(@value,1,1,'')
    select UserID,UserName,@value from vwfinal
```

The above code will append all the `@LoopCounter` variable as a string along with a comma at first.

using `set @value=STUFF(@value,1,1,'')` we replace the first comma with a empty space.

You are getting a conversion error because `@LoopCounter` is of type `INT` and you are trying to append it to `varchar`. If you want to do so, you have to `CONVERT` or `CAST` the `@LoopCounter` variable to `varchar`

If you have an older version of SQL Server you can go for traditional way of appending and creating the required string format as below:

```
set @value=@value + ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@LoopCounter) + ']'
```

Comment: if i passing this means spasdf 1,5 it result is [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]. There no comma is there i Want comma also

Comment: @Vinoth That's because you had kept the `set @value` inside the while loop. It will set `@value` at each loop and it selects the last value of `@value` i.e the 5th loop.

Comment: @Vinoth, Updated my answer

Comment: ok sir my expected result is @value=[1],[2],[3],[4] when i am giving my parameter in strored procedure like this spasdf 1,4. How can i get the result like this

Comment: @Vinoth, if you pass 1,4 it will set @LoopCounter=2 since you have a statement  `@LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1`. If you want `[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]` pass `0` as `@sdate` and `4` as `@edate`

Comment: @Vinoth If your expected result for `@value` is `[1],[2],[3],[4]` give parameters as `spasdf 0,3`

Comment: if i give spasdf 5,8 means i want my result like this [5],[6],[7],[8] then how can i get the result

Comment: @Vinoth, According to your code if you give `spasdf 5,8` it will give you result `[6],[7],[8],[9]` and if you want `[5],[6],[7],[8]`, give  `spasdf 4,7`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your output, consider declaring @value and select statement outside the while loop.

Try replacing the line:

```
set @value='['+@LoopCounter+']'
```

With this:

```
set @value= CONCAT(@value,'['+cast(@LoopCounter as varchar)+'],')
```

And to remove the last comma from value, you can use something like:

```
Select UserID,UserName, substring(@value, 1, (len(@value) - 1)) as Value
```

Comment: if i passing this means spasdf 1,5 it result is [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]. There no comma is there i Want comma also

Comment: You can always add a comma in string. Updated my answer. you can check now.

Answer (score 0):

to get expected result [1],[2],[3],[4],[5] you need something like:

```
create proc spasdf
@sdate int,
@edate int
as

declare @value varchar(300) = ''
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = @sdate
WHILE ( @LoopCounter <= @edate)
BEGIN

    SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1

    set @value= @value + ',['+ CAST(@LoopCounter AS VARCHAR(50)) +']'    
END
    select UserID,UserName,STUFF(@value,1,1,'') as Value from vwfinal
```

Comment: Value Column Shows Null

Comment: changed it to assign default empty string, try now.